# Node/Express return error to main function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, for-of-loop

I'm in a situation where I have a POST route that calls a function multiple times. I want the request to return an error if the *called function returns an error*, but I am not sure how to achieve this. See this image:

[image]

This is my code:

```
function POSTcord(lat, lng) {
    axios
    .post(process.env.SOS_POST_URL + process.env.SOS_POST_CODE, {
        batteryLevel: 100,
        longitude: lng,
        latitude: lat
    })
    .then(res => {
        console.log(`statusCode: ${res.status}`)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error.message);
    })
}

router.post('/test', async (req, res) => {
    let passedCords = req.body;
    try {
        for (const cord of passedCords) {
            POSTcord(cord.lat, cord.lng);
        }
        res.status(200).json({status:"success", message: "hello!"});
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send("Server error");
      }
});
```

I want the route `/test` to return an error if the function `POSTcord` catches an error somewhere in the loop. Any ideas on this? I'm thinking I could pass `res` to `POSTcord` function, but that didn't work. Thankful for any input :)

Comment: Multiple problems: your `POSTcord` function doesn't `return` anything, you're not `await`ing the `POSTcord()` call, and even if you did both then `.catch(error => { console.error(error.message); })` would swallow any error and simply return `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **return** the Promise and make sure the error is thrown/rejected:

Either do this:

```
function POSTcord(lat, lng) {
    return axios // <--------------- THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT
    .post(process.env.SOS_POST_URL + process.env.SOS_POST_CODE, {
        batteryLevel: 100,
        longitude: lng,
        latitude: lat
    })
    .then(res => {
        console.log(`statusCode: ${res.status}`)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error.message);
        throw error; // <----------- ALSO DO THIS
    })
}
```

Or do this:

```
function POSTcord(lat, lng) {
    return axios // <--------------- THIS IS VERY IMPORTANT
    .post(process.env.SOS_POST_URL + process.env.SOS_POST_CODE, {
        batteryLevel: 100,
        longitude: lng,
        latitude: lat
    })
    .then(res => {
        console.log(`statusCode: ${res.status}`)
    })
    // DON'T CATCH THE ERROR!!
}
```

Then all you need to do is `await` to get the error:

```
router.post('/test', async (req, res) => {
    let passedCords = req.body;
    try {
        for (const cord of passedCords) {
            await POSTcord(cord.lat, cord.lng); // DO THIS FOR CATCH TO WORK
        }
        res.status(200).json({status:"success", message: "hello!"});
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send("Server error");
      }
});
```

If you want to call `POSTcord()` in parallel you can `await` using `Promise.all()`:

```
router.post('/test', async (req, res) => {
    let passedCords = req.body;
    try {
        let promises = [];
        for (const cord of passedCords) {
            let p = POSTcord(cord.lat, cord.lng);
            promises.push(p);
        }

        await Promise.all(promises); // DO THIS FOR CATCH TO WORK

        res.status(200).json({status:"success", message: "hello!"});
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send("Server error");
      }
});
```